# Get topic name from Spring Cloud Stream MessageChannel

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

We are using Kafka Cloud Stream in a Spring Boot application to send data to Kafka.
like this

```
producerChannel.send(MessageBuilder
                    .withPayload(data)
                    .setHeader(MessageHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .build())
```

I would like to know whether it's possible to get topic name from the MessageChannel, other than reading directly from yaml file?

```
@Output("topic-name-out")
MessageChannel producerChannel();
```

Topic name is present in a kafka.yaml

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        topic-name-out:
          destination: topic_name_to_producer
          contentType: application/json
          producer:
            partitionCount: ${partition_count:3}
```

Comment: you can inject it via spring as `BindingServiceProperties`.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using annotation-based programming model (e.g., `@Output`). It has been deprecated for 3+ years and is being removed from the code base.
Please upgrade to functional model.

As for your question about `destination` name that is configured externally, there is a way to access it programmatically via Bindings, but I am more curious as to why do you need it as it is an internal detail and also given that it is externally configurable it can change without notice, thus affecting your code.

Comment: in my case I need it for create `NewTopic` for parkingLot with existed destination name. This is better than I hard code its name.

Comment: I am still not sure what you are trying to say. What do you mean hard code? It is property based and as such you benefit by providing such property as command line argument, thus making it as dynamic as it can be.

Comment: I used for this: `bindingServiceProperties.getBindingProperties(NOTIFICATION_NAME).getDestination()+ ".parkingLot"; `  
Yes, I know what you say and I know maybe this is not best way but I didn't found anything else :)

Comment: We've got several hundred bindings and are not ready to migrate. A legit use case for this is detecting misconfiguration. For instance, binding an Input and Output to the same channel name can result in an infinite loop of messages getting sent. A little disappointing to see that this is not available programatically. While the destination _could_ change, I don't think that's a common use case.

Comment: Fortunately I have static bindings defined in configuration, so I can determine destination based on that, but it would have been easier to just have it available programatically.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a bean and bind it to the producer topic

```
@Bean
MessageChannel producerLogger(){
   return (message,l)->{
      RecordMetadata meta = message.getHeaders().get(KafkaHeaders.RECORD_METADATA, RecordMetadata.class);
            Object txnId = message.getHeaders().get("txnId");
            if (Objects.nonNull(meta) && Objects.nonNull(txnId) && txnId instanceof byte[]) {
                log.trace("Topic [{}] Partition [{}] Offset [{}] TxnId [{}]", meta.topic(), meta.partition(), meta.offset(),
                    new String((byte[]) txnId));
            }
    }
```

return true;
}

This will give you topic, parition and offeset to which your application is producing the message.